# Layz loaded list gets reset upon detach from EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have lazy 1:n relation from `Bp` to `BpHistorisiert`.

To load a `Bp` including the related `BpHistorisiert` id do

```
    Bp bp= entityManager.find(Bp.class, anId);
    bp.getBpHistorisiertList();
```

This works fine, the call to `getBpHistorisiertList()` loads the n side lazy as expected. However when bp gets detached, the bpHistorisiert List in bp is explicitely reset to `null`. I can see in the debugger that this is explicitely done by the detach funcionality of the OpenJPA `EntityManager`.

So my question is: How to load lazy relations and keep the values when I work with detached entities?

**Bp**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BP", schema = "INFOP_STAMMDATEN")
public class Bp extends BaseEntity implements EntityId, Serializable {

    /** technische ID */
    @Id
    @Column(name = ID)
    private Long id;

    @Valid
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bp", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<BpHistorisiert> bpHistorisiertList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

**BpHistorisiert**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BP_HISTORISIERT", schema = "INFOP_STAMMDATEN")
public class BpHistorisiert implements EntityId, GueltigkeitOwner, AbkuerzungOwner, Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = ID)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = BP_ID)
    @ForeignKey
    private Bp bp;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @crizzis answer I found the reason for this behaviour. We actually have set

```
<property name="openjpa.DetachState" value="fetch-groups(DetachedStateField=true)"/>
```

in our `persistence.xml`. The consequence is, that all lazy fileds of all entities are set to the java default value up on detach. For a lazy `List` this is `null`.

So yes, this is an OpenJPA feature, not a bug.

And after all this is even explizitely documented: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1913?attachmentSortBy=fileName

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: by reporting an issue on OpenJPA issue tracker and waiting for resolution.

According to [the docs](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.0/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#ref_guide_detach_graph), you should not observe the behavior you described.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but at least pointing me into the right direction. Thanks!